# BeaufifulSoup, lxml navigation for tag with "-" in the tag name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

```
<body>
<response status="success">
<policy>
<shared/>
<panorama>
<address>
    <entry name="text">
    <tag1></tag1>>
    <tag2></tag2>
    </entry>>
</address>
<service>
....
</service>
<pre-rulebase>
</pre-rulebase>
<security>
<rules>
    <entry name="some text">
    <tag1>text</tag1>>
    <tag2>text</tag2>
    </entry>
    <entry name="more text">
    <tag1>text</tag1>
    <tag2>text</tag2>
    </entry>
    ...
    </rules>
</security>
<post-rulebase>
    <entry name="some text">
    <tag1>text</tag1>>
    <tag2>text</tag2>
    </entry>
    <entry name="more text">
    <tag1>text</tag1>>
    <tag2>text</tag2>
    </entry>
</post-rulebase>
</panorama>
</policy>
</response> 
</body>
```

Hi,

I am trying to parse above xml file using Python BeautifulSoup and lxml. Usually I navigate to the element using '.'.
e.g.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('sample.xml', 'r') as xml_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file, 'lxml')

for item in soup.body.response.policy.panorama.address.find('entry'):
    <some code action>
```

My problem is with navigating via above for tags like '' and ''. Since there is "-" in the tag name, the "." navigation is not working. Also since the child tags have same names, i cannot use it direct find. How can I navigate and iterate thru tags under '' i.e. '' tags?

Comment: What information do you need to find? Please, edit your question and post there expected output.

Comment: What do you mean by "." navigation not working?

Comment: I need to find <entry> tags under <post-rulebase>. Sorry the xml copy/paste was missing few tags. <post-rulebase><security><rules><entry name="text1"><entry name="text2"></rules></security></post-rulebase>.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do it like this:

```
from lxml import etree
rules = """[your xml, fixed]"""
doc = etree.XML(rules)
for i in doc.xpath('//post-rulebase//entry'):
    print(i.tag,i.attrib['name'])
    for t in i.xpath('.//*'):
        print(t.tag,t.text)
```

Output:

```
entry some text
tag1 text
tag2 text
entry more text
tag1 text
tag2 text
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req, utils
html = '''
<address>
    <entry name="text">
    <tag1></tag1>>
    <tag2></tag2>
    </entry>>
</address>
<service>
....
</service>
<post-rulebase>
    <entry name="some text">
    <tag1>text</tag1>>
    <tag2>text</tag2>
    </entry>
    <entry name="more text">
    <tag1>text</tag1>>
    <tag2>text</tag2>
    </entry>
</post-rulebase>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
entry = doc.select('post-rulebase').entry
print(entry)
print(entry.children.text)
```

Result:

```
{'name': 'some text', 'tag': 'entry', 'html': '\n    <tag1>text</tag1>>\n    <tag2>text</tag2>\n    '}
['text', 'text']
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples